# How to resolve (40: Too many levels of symbolic links) on Ubuntu 10.04 AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, django

In my EC2 Ubuntu 18.04 instance, I have created an **django.conf** file at */etc/nginx/sites-available*

The .conf file looks like so :

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name *[url_name]*;

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/ZTS-JOBCARDS/app.sock;
        }

}
```

and when I ran `sudo nginx -t` before trying to link the files to **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/** the result came back positive

However, after I had linked the files like so: `sudo ln -s django.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

The `nginx -t` command returns the following error ;

> nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django.conf" failed
> (40: Too many levels of symbolic links) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62
> nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

What would cause this error and are their any guides to fixing it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have linked `django.conf` back to itself. There's no data in the file, just a reference to itself.

This command,

```
ln -s django.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/    # Wrong
```

creates a symbolic link in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` called `django.conf`, pointing to `django.conf`. You can see this with `ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django.conf`.

What you intended was this, which creates a symbolic link in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` called `django.conf` pointing to the relative location, `../sites-available/django.conf`

```
cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled && ln -s ../sites-available/django.conf
```

If you want to avoid changing your current directory, wrap the pair of commands in brackets

```
( cd … && ln … )
```