# ungit crashes on Debian 11 bullseye - ELOOP - too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: linux, debian, npm, javascript

Tried to install and run git GUI 'ungit' on Debian 11. The default versions for npm and nodejs from Debian were too old for ungit, so I updated them manually, but ungit still crashes.
**Versions**

- git: 2.39.3
- npm: 9.6 7
- nodejs: 18.17.1
- ungit: 1.5.24+70b8cab0
- os: Debian 11 bullseye

In command line:

> ungit

gives output:

> Setting log level to warn Ungit started Took 367ms to start server.
> Navigate to
> http://localhost:8448/#/repository?path=/home/linus/git/project_part8/
> 2023-08-29T14:37:39.308Z - error: Error: ELOOP: too many symbolic
> links encountered, stat
> '/home/linus/git/project_part8/src/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp  /bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp  /bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp/bsp'
> at Object.statSync (node:fs:1690:3) at
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ungit/node_modules/node-watch/lib/is.js:65:17
> at checkStat
> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ungit/node_modules/node-watch/lib/is.js:12:12)
> at Object.directory
> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ungit/node_modules/node-watch/lib/is.js:64:12)
> at
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ungit/node_modules/node-watch/lib/watch.js:153:18
> at Array.forEach () at
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ungit/node_modules/node-watch/lib/watch.js:151:13
> at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:200:23) Stopped keeping ungit
> alive

Web browser says:

> Whooops Unfortunately ungit interrupted its work because: disconnected

What should I do to make ungit run properly?

If this issue relates to a similar [old issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141436/too-many-levels-of-symbolic-links), could someone explain more in detail? It's not clear to me

Comment: Please run `ls -ld /home/linus/git/project_part8/src/bsp` and add the output to your original question post.